# get current position / time of file in superpowered decoder while decoding

Tags: superpowered

While decoding file using superpowered i get **samplePosition** but i want current position in miliseconds / seconds. **samplePosition** is the current position in samples. but what i actually need is current position in milliseconds. while decoding i want to mute / unmute at certain millisecond positions in audio file.

```
while (true) {

    currentSamplesDecoded = decoder->samplesPerFrame;
    status = decoder->decode(intBuffer, &currentSamplesDecoded);

    baseCurrentPosition = decoder->samplePosition;

    // What i want is :- 
    // currentMiliseconds = decoder-> how to get current position in Miliseconds

}
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

**Math!**, I was not sure about the terms of **samplePosition** and **durationSamples**

```
decoder->durationSeconds * ((double)decoder->samplePosition / (double)decoder->durationSamples)
```

So it seems **samplePosition** divide by **durationSamples** gives **% progress**

**Thank You**